# A better way to cluster items

Tags: graph-algorithms, clustering, data-mining

I am working on a text processer which gives out similarities between a set of strings. After weighted [LCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and [double metaphone matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone), I get buckets of strings such as

- Bucket for string $i \rightarrow [s, k, m]$
- Bucket for string $j \rightarrow [i, s, k]$

This effectively implies that $i,j,s,k,m$ belong to the same cluster.

One of the ways I could do this is to build a connectivity graph and cluster all the connected components.

The other way is to iteratively check for the matches.

Could somebody help me do it better.

Comment: What is "better" ? if the only information you have is the connectivity structure, then you need graph based approaches, and spectral methods might be of use.

Comment: So i used the connectivity analysis to deal with it. Its real fast.

Comment: @Suresh Venkat I am more interested in learning what spectral methods you were referring to.

Comment: Look for spectral graph partitioning on google. The idea is to use the connectivity (as encoded by the Laplacian) to split the graph into pieces.